# Referência de classe afetando estrutura

Tags: c#

Estou com um pequeno problema e não estou conseguindo resolver.

Eu tenho uma classe (matriz 0~999) chamada `pTest`, ela já está instanciada tudo certinho.

Após eu instanciar eu copio uma estrutura que é do jogador (contém informações de nome, nível, etc.) de outra classe pra vincular dentro da `pTest`.

Por exemplo:

```
pTest[0].Player = g_kNPCGener.kMonster[0].MOB;
```

Se eu fizer assim em um método:

```
pTest[0].Player = g_kNPCGener.kMonster[0].MOB;
pTest[1].Player = g_kNPCGener.kMonster[0].MOB;

pTest[0].Player.Name = "Grim";
```

o `pTest[1].Player.Name` também ficará com o valor "Grim".

A estrutura `pTest[0].Player` é a mesma estrutura (struct) do `Monster.List[0].NPC`;

```
public class TmController 
{
    public MobTest[] pTest = new MobTest[1000];

    // methods..

    public void init()
    {
        pTest[0].Player = g_kNPCGener.kMonster[0].MOB;

        pTest[0].Mode = 1;

        pTest[1].Player = g_kNPCGener.kMonster[0].MOB;

        pTest[1].Mode = 1;
    }

    public TmController()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pTest.Length; i++)
        {
            pTest[i] = new MobTest();
        }
    }
}

public class MobTest : TmController
{
    public STRUCT_MOB Player;

    public int Mode;

    public MobTest()
    {
        Player = STRUCT_MOB.Clear();

        Mode = 0;
    }
}
```

lembrando que, se eu alterar a propriedade `Mode` do objeto `pTest[0]`, por exemplo: `pTest[0].Mode = 5`, ele não faz alteração no `pTest[1].Mode`.

Como solucionar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Do Microsoft Docs:

> No C# há dois tipos de valores, os "tipos de referência" ([*reference types*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)) e os "tipos de valor" ([*value types*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)). Variáveis de tipos de referência armazenam referências aos seus dados (objetos), enquanto que variáveis de tipos de valor diretamente contém seus dados.

Estruturas (*structs*) são tipos de valor, ao contrário de classes, que são tipos de referência, o que significa que ao atribuir o valor de uma variável de um tipo `struct` para outra variável de mesmo tipo, os valores dessa estrutura serão copiados para a nova variável, **mas**, somente os membros da estrutura que também são tipos de valor serão copiados, no caso de membros da estrutura que sejam tipos de referência, somente a referência ao objeto será copiada.

O que acontece é que o tipo `string` é um tipo de referência, e não um tipo de valor, então, ao "copiar" uma estrutura que contenha membros do tipo `string` de uma variável para outra, você está somente copiando a referência do seu campo `string`, o que significa que ambas estruturas fazem referência ao mesmo objeto `string`.

Para resolver isso talvez você tivesse que implementar um método `Copy()` na sua estrutura, que soubesse como fazer uma nova cópia da estrutura, de forma correta. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
public struct STRUCT_MOB
{
   public int X, Y;
   public string Name;

   public STRUCT_MOB Copy()
   {
      STRUCT_MOB newMob = this;
      newMob.Name = string.Copy(this.Name);
      return newMob;
   }
}
```

Então ao invés de fazer assim:

```
    pTest[0].Player = g_kNPCGener.kMonster[0].MOB;
    pTest[0].Mode = 1;
    pTest[1].Player = g_kNPCGener.kMonster[0].MOB;
    pTest[1].Mode = 1;
```

Você faria assim:

```
    pTest[0].Player = g_kNPCGener.kMonster[0].MOB;
    pTest[0].Mode = 1;
    pTest[1].Player = g_kNPCGener.kMonster[0].MOB.Copy();
    pTest[1].Mode = 1;
```

Fontes:

> https://stackoverflow.com/q/11336935/8133067
>   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/633c7c7b-4167-4c90-835e-ee6e8b566156/
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs